# Persistant horizontal "screen tearing" issue visible on in-browser videos

Tags: video, display, screen-tearing

For the past few months at least, I've noticed a persistent screen tearing problem when I watch Youtube videos (or other video formats, for that matter) on my browser. [Here is an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDesq.jpg) - I took screenshots of Youtube running in Brave to capture the exact issue. You can actually see it in at least three different locations; it almost looks as though a few horizontal lines of pixels are missing in those spots, because it's not a simple lateral shift. [Bizarrely, a tearing test video produces no such artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ze0.jpg); this again reinforces my "missing lines of pixels" idea, and that it's not really true screen tearing.

I currently use Brave Browser, but I used to use Chrome and also had this issue (Brave is based on Chrome anyway, I believe). I just checked and the issue does not occur with Internet Explorer (that still exists?) or Microsoft Edge. I think we can safely say this has something to do with the Brave/Chrome browser.

I'm running an i5-4590 with a Sapphire RX 580 outputting 1080p/144Hz through displayport to a Viewsonic XG2401 as my primary monitor. I also have a second 1080p monitor hooked up most of the time, and I also use a Vizio M65 tv as a display through HDMI (also through the RX 580). This issue is present no matter which configuration of monitors I have - one, two, all three, etc.

I've researched this for hours and haven't been able to find any sort of solution. I've tried digging into Chrome flags to fiddle with hardware acceleration settings and such, to no effect. Yes my GPU driver is up to date. Yes Brave is up to date. Does anybody have any idea how I can fix this? I'm pretty tech-savvy and can provide whatever info you need.

Thanks in advance.